# Reporting Segments table not being populated 9.0.1

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1 and I'm following the [Troubleshooting xDB data issues](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) guide. My scenario is #2 where data is being collected but I see nothing on the Experience Analytics reports (there's some old data from months ago but not current data).

Scenario 2 Step 3 asks us to "Ensure that the Segments table of the reporting SQL database is not empty" and my Segments table *is* empty. To populate this table I read that I should run the `Control Panel > Analytics > Deploy marketing definitions` option, but after running this and checking the table it's still empty :(

Why is it that the Segments table is not being populated? Anyone has any workaround for this? I'm out of options and without data on this table I've read that the reports will not show up. I get no error on the CM logs or on the PROC logs.

```
Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
December 19, 2017
.NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
```

Comment: I'd recommend rebuilding your reporting db.

Comment: Hello Mark, I've tried that but for some reason rebuilding the reporting db always gets stuck somewhere and slows down to few items per second.

Comment: You definitely need to fix that. There is a known issue in 9.0.1 with CES service causing slow down. Patch available on kb website.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here and tried deploying marketing definitions and rebuild the reporting database and it doesn't work, same sitecore version 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
any update what to do else here?

Comment: Hello there, I was informed by Sitecore that the table for version 9.0.1 is on the ReferenceData database and it's now called 'Definitions'

Answer (score 5):

I was informed by Sitecore that the table for version 9.0.1 is now on the `ReferenceData` database and it's called `Definitions`.